# Adding buttons to Hbox

Tags: button, javafx

Dipping my toes for the first time in javaFX and I'm having some problems with adding buttons to a Hbox. It seems like the box doesn't like the type buttons being added. Have no clue why, so just cheking if this has happened to anyone else.

```
Button knapp1 = new Button("Alphabetical");
Button knapp2 = new Button("Frequency");
HBox hbox = new HBox();
hbox.getChildren().addAll(knapp1, knapp2);
```

It's the "addAll" method that's the problem, it gives the error

> The method `addAll(int, Collection<? extends Node>` in the type `List
>   <Node>` is not applicable for the arguments `(Button, Buttons)` )

Thanks in advance for what may be a stupid question.

Comment: Check you have the right imports.

Comment: As @James_D pointed out, can you check that you have this: import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;

Comment: @Boris Surely it's the `Button` import, not the `HBox`, that's likely to be the problem?

Comment: You're right. Then, probably, it's wrong `java.awt.Button` import instead of `javafx.scene.control.Button`

Comment: I'm unsure why it considers `knapp2` to be of type `Buttons` (note the `s`) according to the compile time error... Are you sure everything is posted exactly the way it occurs in your code?

Comment: Yepp thath was the problem, imported the wrong thing, thanks! :)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a runnable example as said in the comments check your imports

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Button knapp1 = new Button("Alphabetical");
        Button knapp2 = new Button("Frequency");
        HBox hbox = new HBox();
        hbox.getChildren().addAll(knapp1, knapp2);
        Scene scene = new Scene(hbox);
        stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```

When run with these imports

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.awt.*;
```

I get the same error as you remove the `import java.awt.*;` and replace with `import javafx.scene.control.Button;`